Problem with topology
I would like to ask, if someone is able to give me some advice about the topology of this character (I need it as game asset).
My problem is that when I apply the “shade smooth”, my character gets some shadows on the leg and under the arm. Another problem is that it’s not completely smooth and some visible edges remain, such as on the chest or near the neck
Is my topology so bad? Do I have to do it again, or can I improve it somehow?
Thank you in advance







Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Have you tried using the Subdivision Surface modifier instead?

I've uploaded the file with the mesh topology. I tried to use the subdivision surface but it doesn't help

you have to copy the link of the upload to your question so that we can access it

ops sorry, here the link 

It's opinion based, but the topology would probably be considered "bad" by most professionals. It's too dense, the forms could be held by less topology and it could be more evenly distributed and aligned with likely deformations. If this is for learning, that's great, you should practice and try to do it. If you need a character that is generic human shaped, don't waste your time reinventing the wheel. Human anatomy has been modeled millions of times. Try MakeHuman, it's Blender add-on or any one of hundreds of humanoid generators.

I don't mean to just use it as is. I mean, you can definitely start with something already made. I also think this might not be a completely bad idea from the perspective of learning, because the basic forms are generally OK with most of these generators so there are things to learn from them, but there is also plenty of space to improve depending on your circumstances as they are quite generic. Nothing wrong to take something that is already made for a starting point and modify it as you need.

It has nothing to do with your topology, it's because you've enabled the Shadow option in the Viewport Shading tab, it's the projected shadow of the other leg:

